# In Mysql, select distinct values that occur with each instance of another value

Tags: mysql

I have a table with supplier id's (sid), part id's (pid), and job id's (jid).  Each have many instances, but I need to find suppliers that occur with each part.

Here is an example table:

```
+------+------+------+------+
| sid  | pid  | jid  | qty  |
+------+------+------+------+
| S1   | P1   | J1   |  200 |
| S1   | P1   | J4   |  700 |
| S2   | P3   | J1   |  400 |
| S2   | P3   | J2   |  200 |
| S2   | P3   | J3   |  200 |
| S2   | P3   | J4   |  500 |
| S2   | P3   | J5   |  600 |
| S2   | P3   | J6   |  400 |
| S2   | P3   | J7   |  800 |
| S3   | P3   | J1   |  200 |
| S3   | P4   | J2   |  500 |
| S4   | P6   | J3   |  300 |
| S4   | P6   | J7   |  300 |
| S5   | P2   | J2   |  200 |
| S5   | P2   | J4   |  100 |
| S5   | P5   | J5   |  500 |
| S5   | P5   | J7   |  100 |
| S5   | P6   | J2   |  200 |
| S5   | P1   | J4   |  100 |
| S5   | P3   | J4   |  200 |
| S5   | P4   | J4   |  800 |
| S5   | P5   | J4   |  400 |
| S5   | P6   | J4   |  500 |
+------+------+------+------+
```

So this should return

```
+------+
| sid  | 
+------+
| S5   |
+------+
```

Since S5 is the only supplier id that occurs with all 6 of the parts (pid).  I figure I would use subselects, but have no idea how to go about doing this.

Comment: Another way to think of it is to try to find the negative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT sid
FROM mytable
GROUP BY sid
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT pid) = (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT pid) FROM mytable)
```

The subquery:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT pid) FROM mytable
```

returns the number of distinct part numbers existing in your table. The main query groups by `sid` and its `HAVING` clause selects only `sid` groups that contain all existing part numbers.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5a4d09/1)

Comment: If there is no entry for any of 6 `pid` in table, your query will still produce result although there should be no result, as there is no such `sid` with all `pid`.

Comment: @JitendraSoftgrid I assume that `pid` is a not nullable field. Otherwise the question doesn't make much sense.

Comment: I agree with that 'I assume that pid is a not nullable field', but I was thinking if there is no such row with `p2`.

Comment: @JitendraSoftgrid We need to somehow obtain the list of all possible product numbers. It is up to the OP to adjust the query in order to correctly obtain this list. He can alternatively hard code or read it from a lookup table.

Comment: Yeah, it depends on what OP wants.